# Trying to test Paypal IPN with Sandbox, but handshake does not go through

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to get Paypal IPN set up and cannot figure out what is wrong with the code I have written below. When I try to test it with Paypal's Sandbox IPN Simulator, it returns "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information." I think that the problem is something with the headers needing to be changed to a sanbox freindly format, but cannot figure out exactly what I need to change.

This is the URL that the code is under:
http://pmoore17.altervista.org/TWADrama/ticketsales1.php

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
<?php
// Read the notification from PayPal which comes in the form of a POST array and create the acknowledgement response
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // add 'cmd' to beginning of the acknowledgement you send back to PayPal

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{ // Loop through the notification NV pairs
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode the values
$req .= "&$key=$value";                    // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
}


// Assign the paypal payment notification values to local variables
if($_POST){
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];}

//Set up the acknowledgement request headers (this is the updated version for http 1.1)
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
//Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
$fq = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if(!$fq){
    echo "HTTP ERROR";
}
else
{//start 1

// Post request back to PayPal for validation
fputs ($fq, $header . $req);

//once paypal receives the acknowledgement response, another message will be send containing the single word VERIFIED or INVALID

while (!feof($fq)) 
    { //start 2, while not EndOfFile
$res = fgets ($fq, 1024); // Get the acknowledgement response
$res = trim($res);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
        {// start 3, Response is OK
        $fn = "content.txt";
$fp = fopen($fn,"a+") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
fputs($fp,"last_name: ".$last_name.", ");
fputs($fp,"first_name: ".$first_name.", ");
fputs($fp,"quantity: ".$quantity.", ");
fputs($fp,"payer_email: ".$payer_email."\n");
fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
        }//end 3
        else if(strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
            {//start 4
            $fn = "content.txt";
$fp = fopen($fn,"a+") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
fputs($fp,"last_name: ".$last_name.", ");
fputs($fp,"first_name: ".$first_name.", ");
fputs($fp,"quantity: ".$quantity.", ");
fputs($fp,"payer_email: ".$payer_email."\n");
fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
            }//end 4


} //end 2
fclose ($fq);  //close file pointer
} //end 1
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
//Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
$fq = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

To this:

```
//Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
$fq = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **verify the incoming notification** by using the old Paypal SDK instead of crafting your own (usually wrong) solution. With composer:

`$ composer require paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php`

or download the SDK manually. Then verify it using the `PPIPNMessage` class:

```
// you can omit both arguments, mode defaults to "live"
$ipn = new PPIPNMessage('', ['mode' => 'sandbox']);
$valid = $ipn->validate(); // returns bool
$data = $ipn->getRawData(); // returns the IPN notification as array

// continue with things
```

Maybe it's too much to get the whole SDK just for one class, but that's your choice anyways :)

Comment: Also for the last couple of days the `notify_url` override in your buttons/links does not work (it seems). I am not receiving the IPN notifications since the last Amazon/GoDaddy/other fancy big "cloud" guys disruptions. Not saying it's related, just flagging the moment.

Comment: You don't need the whole SDK, you can get just the IPN code here https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php  For last few days, IPN simulator has not been working for me, but I AM getting IPN notification when doing a payment to paypal.com or sandbox.paypal.com